# MySQL Count for the number of times a specific column appears after grouping

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my query:

```
SELECT 
    mh.super_category AS parentDescription, 
    mh.super_category AS parentSlug, 
    mh.description AS subDescription, 
    mh.slug AS subSlug, 
    COUNT(mh.slug) AS qty,
    cg.Description AS nestedSubDescription, 
    cg.slug AS nestedSubSlug 
FROM Categories AS c
    INNER JOIN Category_Groups AS cg ON (c.Category_Group=cg.CategoryCode) 
    INNER JOIN menu_heading AS mh ON (cg.MenuHeading = mh.id)
    INNER JOIN tbl_store_brands ON (tbl_store_brands.categoryID = c.pkID) 
WHERE c.seq <> 127 
GROUP BY cg.slug 
ORDER BY mh.super_category, mh.seq ASC, cg.seq, c.seq, c.Category_Group, c.Category_ID
```

And this is a representation of the results returned:

```
+-------------------+------------+----------------+--------------------+-----+--------------------------+--------------------------+
| parentDescription | parentSlug | subDescription |      subSlug       | qty |   nestedSubDescription   |      nestedSubSlug       |
+-------------------+------------+----------------+--------------------+-----+--------------------------+--------------------------+
| Appliances        | Appliances | Washers/Dryers | washers-dryers     |  50 | Washers                  | washers                  |
| Appliances        | Appliances | Washers/Dryers | washers-dryers     |  68 | Dryers                   | dryers                   |
| Appliances        | Appliances | Washers/Dryers | washers-dryers     |   5 | Stack Laundry            | stack-laundry            |
| Appliances        | Appliances | Washers/Dryers | washers-dryers     |  13 | Laundry Accessories      | laundry-accessories      |
| Appliances        | Appliances | Refrigerators  | refrigerators      |  48 | French Door              | french-door              |
| Appliances        | Appliances | Refrigerators  | refrigerators      |  40 | Side by Side             | side-by-side             |
| Appliances        | Appliances | Refrigerators  | refrigerators      |  24 | Bottom Freezer           | bottom-freezer           |
| Appliances        | Appliances | Refrigerators  | refrigerators      |  16 | Top Mount                | top-mount                |
| Appliances        | Appliances | Refrigerators  | refrigerators      |  37 | Built In                 | built-in                 |
| Appliances        | Appliances | Refrigerators  | refrigerators      |  82 | Specialty                | specialty                |
| Appliances        | Appliances | Refrigerators  | refrigerators      |  66 | Freezers                 | freezers                 |
| Appliances        | Appliances | Refrigerators  | refrigerators      |  20 | Refrigerator Accessories | refrigerator-accessories |
+-------------------+------------+----------------+--------------------+-----+--------------------------+--------------------------+
```

The figure returned in the qty column is the count of how many times mh.slug would appear without the group condition but what I actually want is how many times it appears in the query i.e. 4 for washer-dryers.

How can I achieve this ?

New Sample Results

```
+--------------------------+--------------------------+---+------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------+
| Refrigerators | refrigerators | French Door              | french-door              | 9 | Cabinet Depth: French Door         | cabinet-depth-french-door-refrigerators   |
| Refrigerators | refrigerators | Side by Side             | side-by-side             | 9 | Side x Side: with Dispenser        | side-by-side-with-dispenser-refrigerators |
| Refrigerators | refrigerators | Bottom Freezer           | bottom-freezer           | 9 | Bottom Freezer                     | bottom-freezer-refrigerators              |
| Refrigerators | refrigerators | Top Mount                | top-mount                | 9 | Top Freezer                        | top-freezer-refrigerators                 |
| Refrigerators | refrigerators | Built In                 | built-in                 | 9 | Built-in Columns Refrigerator Only | built-in-columns-refrigerator-only        |
| Refrigerators | refrigerators | Specialty                | specialty                | 9 | Wine Storage                       | wine-storage                              |
| Refrigerators | refrigerators | Freezers                 | freezers                 | 9 | Icemaker Kits                      | icemaker-kits-refrigerator                |
| Refrigerators | refrigerators | Refrigerator Accessories | refrigerator-accessories | 9 | Refrigerator Accessories           | refrigeration-accessories                 |
+---------------+---------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+---+------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: You typically GROUP BY the columns you select, except those who are arguments to set functions.

Comment: First you should rewrite your SQL because you are misusing MySQL GROUP BY feature.. https://www.psce.com/en/blog/2012/05/15/mysql-mistakes-do-you-use-group-by-correctly/

Comment: I have edited my query so that the group by clause is a column from the query

Comment: I hope I understand you correctly. Try replacing `COUNT(mh.slug) AS qty` by `(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Category_Groups AS countCg WHERE countCg.MenuHeading = mh.id) As qty`

This is supposing that every mh.id has an unique mh.slug.

Comment: @Roemer that is perfect thank you, because it is a comment I can't except it as an answer if you want to add it as an answer I will accept it.
Many thanks

Comment: Glad I could help. I entered it as an answer, also for future Googelers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    mh.super_category AS parentDescription, 
    mh.super_category AS parentSlug, 
    mh.description AS subDescription, 
    mh.slug AS subSlug, 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Category_Groups AS countCg WHERE countCg.MenuHeading = mh.id) As qty,
    cg.Description AS nestedSubDescription, 
    cg.slug AS nestedSubSlug 
FROM Categories AS c
    INNER JOIN Category_Groups AS cg ON (c.Category_Group=cg.CategoryCode) 
    INNER JOIN menu_heading AS mh ON (cg.MenuHeading = mh.id)
    INNER JOIN tbl_store_brands ON (tbl_store_brands.categoryID = c.pkID) 
WHERE c.seq <> 127 
GROUP BY cg.slug 
ORDER BY mh.super_category, mh.seq ASC, cg.seq, c.seq, c.Category_Group, c.Category_ID
```

For your second problem, try this and let me know if it works (haven't got the time to think it 100% through, and I do not know the relationship types, so it is just trial and error here):

```
SELECT 
    mh.super_category AS parentDescription, 
    mh.super_category AS parentSlug, 
    mh.description AS subDescription, 
    mh.slug AS subSlug, 
    cg.Description AS nestedSubDescription, 
    cg.slug AS nestedSubSlug 
    (SELECT COUNT(countCg.*) FROM Categories AS c2 
          INNER JOIN Category_Groups AS countCg 
          INNER JOIN tbl_store_brands tsb2 ON (tsb2 .categoryID = c2.pkID)
      WHERE countCg.MenuHeading = mh.id) As qty
FROM Categories AS c
    INNER JOIN Category_Groups AS cg ON (c.Category_Group=cg.CategoryCode) 
    INNER JOIN menu_heading AS mh ON (cg.MenuHeading = mh.id)
    INNER JOIN tbl_store_brands ON (tbl_store_brands.categoryID = c.pkID) 
WHERE c.seq <> 127 
GROUP BY cg.slug 
ORDER BY mh.super_category, mh.seq ASC, cg.seq, c.seq, c.Category_Group, c.Category_ID
```

Comment: I have a follow up question if I may, your code works exactly as it should but I have noticed an issue where the join to tbl_store_brands excludes a Category_Group because the store doesn't carry that brand so on Refrigerators for example your code returns 9 which is correct as there are 9 in the table but only 8 are actually stocked by the store. The only link from tel_store_brands to Category_Groups is through the Categories table and when I include that join in your code it makes the count 1.
Any idea's on how I can overcome this? I have included a sample set of results in my question.

Comment: Make it a LEFT JOIN in stead of an INNER JOIN, that should do it. INNER JOIN only takes records with records in both tables, a LEFT JOIN takes all the records in the left table regardless if there are records in the right table or not.

Comment: I only want records that match from all tables, the issue is that the count (qty) returns to many records rather than being restricted to the records returned by the main query. Does that make sense?

Comment: Ah sorry, I misunderstood. This is getting complicated.

Comment: Try the extra solution added and let me know if it works. Without an overview of your tables it is inpossible to be sure if this will work, because I do not know the relationships of the tables.

Comment: No this didn't work for me, thank you for your help so far but I need to put this aside for the moment and work on another part of the project. I will post another question when and if I get back to this.